# NSURLConnection still store cache data

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

When I'm using `NSURLConnection` to get data from my server, iOS still cache data. When requesting new data, iOS sending a new request to my server, but the files are still stored.

I'm using `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` and returning nil in `connection:willCacheResponse:`.

The problem is that I'm using my own caching object, and it's kind of dum to let iOS store a duplicate.

Should I ignore this or should I delete the cache somehow?

**Update**

Code for creating `NSURLRequest`:

```
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

Code for creating `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Code for `NSURlConnectionDelegate`:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [recivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (_handler) _handler(response, error, nil);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if (_handler) _handler(response, nil, recivedData);

    recivedData = nil;
    response = nil;
}
```

Comment: This shouldnt be happening. Could you show us how you have initialised the NSURLConnection and the delegates?

Comment: @akashg I've updated with some code. Sorry for the long delay.

Comment: No problem Gustaf. Add a breakpoint and check whether the `willCacheResponse` gets called at all.

Comment: How can you be sure that the caching still occurs?

Comment: In the app folder in finder, can I see that the system is caching data in a SQLite database. The database stores my requests and data.

Comment: The willCacheResponse gets called every request